# React change amount with stripe

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, stripe-payments

I am building a payment app using Stripe and am having some issues changing the amount on button click.

My code:

PaymentForm.js:

```
export default function PaymentForm() {
    const [amountVal, setAmountVal] = useState(0);
    const [success, setSuccess ] = useState(false)
    const stripe = useStripe()
    const elements = useElements()
    


    const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        const {error, paymentMethod} = await stripe.createPaymentMethod({
            type: "card",
            card: elements.getElement(CardElement)
        })


    if(!error) {
        try {
            const {id} = paymentMethod
            const response = await axios.post("http://localhost:3000/donationform", {
                amount: {amountVal},
                id
            })

            if(response.data.success) {
                console.log("Successful payment")
                setSuccess(true)
            }

        } catch (error) {
            console.log("Error", error)
        }
    } else {
        console.log(error.message)
    }
}

    return (
        <>
        {!success ? 
        <div>
            <div>
            <AmountButton onClick={() => setAmountVal(100)}>$1</AmountButton>
            <AmountButton onClick={() => setAmountVal(500)}>$5</AmountButton>
            <AmountButton onClick={() => setAmountVal(1000)}>$10</AmountButton>
            <AmountButton onClick={() => setAmountVal(2000)}>$20</AmountButton>
            <AmountButton onClick={() => setAmountVal(5000)}>$50</AmountButton>
            </div>

        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <FormText style={{ color: '#fff' }}>${amountVal/100}.00</FormText>
            <fieldset className="FormGroup">
                <div className="FormRow">
                    <CardElement options={CARD_OPTIONS}/>
                </div>
            </fieldset>
            <button>Pay</button>
        </form>
        </div>
        :
       <div>
           <FormText style={{ color: '#fff' }}>You're the best! If you have any questions about your donation, you can reach out to us at loopbreak@loopbreakr.com</FormText>
       </div> 
        }
            
        </>
    )
}
```

server.js:

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const cors = require("cors");
const nodemailer = require("nodemailer");
require("dotenv").config();
const stripe = require("stripe")(process.env.STRIPE_SECRET_TEST)

const app = express();
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.urlencoded())
app.use(express.json());
app.use("/", router);

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, () => console.log("Server Running"));

  
  contactEmail.verify((error) => {
    if (error) {
      console.log(error);
    } else {
      console.log("Ready to Send");
    }
  });

  app.post("/donationform", cors(), async (req, res) => {
    let { amount, id } = req.body
    
    try {
      const payment = await stripe.paymentIntents.create({
        amount,
        currency: "USD",
        description: "Loopbreakr",
        payment_method: id,
        confirm: true
      })
      console.log("Payment", payment)
      res.json({
        message: "Payment successful",
        success: true
      })
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("Error", error)
      res.json({
        message: "Payment failed",
        success: false
      })
    }
  })
```

Everything works when I hardcode the amount, but when I tried to change it by clicking buttons it is not posted. However the state is changed as it is reflected in the AmountText field where I display the user option. I get an error that says the following:

```
Error StripeInvalidRequestError: Invalid integer: {:amountVal=>"0"}
    at Function.generate (C:\Users\mirak\loopbreakr-site\server\node_modules\stripe\lib\Error.js:40:16)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (C:\Users\mirak\loopbreakr-site\server\node_modules\stripe\lib\StripeResource.js:180:33)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:421:28)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:327:22)
    at endReadableNT (internal/streams/readable.js:1327:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21) {
  type: 'StripeInvalidRequestError',
  raw: {
    code: 'parameter_invalid_integer',
    doc_url: 'https://stripe.com/docs/error-codes/parameter-invalid-integer',
    message: 'Invalid integer: {:amountVal=>"0"}',
    param: 'amount',
    type: 'invalid_request_error',
    headers: {
      server: 'nginx',
      date: 'Thu, 08 Apr 2021 09:23:40 GMT',
      'content-type': 'application/json',
      'content-length': '261',
      connection: 'keep-alive',
      'access-control-allow-credentials': 'true',
      'access-control-allow-methods': 'GET, POST, HEAD, OPTIONS, DELETE',
      'access-control-allow-origin': '*',
      'access-control-expose-headers': 'Request-Id, Stripe-Manage-Version, X-Stripe-External-Auth-Required, X-Stripe-Privileged-Session-Required',
      'access-control-max-age': '300',
      'cache-control': 'no-cache, no-store',
      'request-id': 'req_O9Z9kCTMpAEmDk',
      'stripe-version': '2020-08-27',
      'x-stripe-c-cost': '0',
      'strict-transport-security': 'max-age=31556926; includeSubDomains; preload'
    },
    statusCode: 400,
    requestId: 'req_O9Z9kCTMpAEmDk'
  },
  rawType: 'invalid_request_error',
  code: 'parameter_invalid_integer',
  doc_url: 'https://stripe.com/docs/error-codes/parameter-invalid-integer',
  param: 'amount',
  detail: undefined,
  headers: {
    server: 'nginx',
    date: 'Thu, 08 Apr 2021 09:23:40 GMT',
    'content-type': 'application/json',
    'content-length': '261',
    connection: 'keep-alive',
    'access-control-allow-credentials': 'true',
    'access-control-allow-methods': 'GET, POST, HEAD, OPTIONS, DELETE',
    'access-control-allow-origin': '*',
    'access-control-expose-headers': 'Request-Id, Stripe-Manage-Version, X-Stripe-External-Auth-Required, X-Stripe-Privileged-Session-Required',
    'access-control-max-age': '300',
    'cache-control': 'no-cache, no-store',
    'request-id': 'req_O9Z9kCTMpAEmDk',
    'stripe-version': '2020-08-27',
    'x-stripe-c-cost': '0',
    'strict-transport-security': 'max-age=31556926; includeSubDomains; preload'
  },
  requestId: 'req_O9Z9kCTMpAEmDk',
  statusCode: 400,
  charge: undefined,
  decline_code: undefined,
  payment_intent: undefined,
  payment_method: undefined,
  payment_method_type: undefined,
  setup_intent: undefined,
  source: undefined
}
```

Comment: Maybe try using `amount : amount.amountVal,` in the backend call to `paymentIntents.create`, since you seem to not be correctly parsing the value your frontend sends you.  (although you can't pass an amount of 0 to Stripe's API either, but the first step is passing the integer value)

Comment: Thank you for your fix and explanation! it all worked :)